# Linux: remove duplicate strings from for and cut

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, find

So I have a file structure that looks like this:

- video

  - abc.avi
  - party_2014.h264
  - test.avi
  - xxx.mkv

I need to create a directory for each  extension and move the corresponding file there so it looks like this

- video

  - video-avi

    - abc.avi
    - test.avi
  - video-h264

    - party_2014.h264
  - video-mkv

    - xxx.mkv

so far I have this code:

```
for i in $(find video -name "*.*" -print)
    do cut -d'.' -f2 <<< "$i" | uniq -c;
done
```

this will return duplicate avi so uniq doesn't seem to be working, how to remove duplicates properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This simple script might work for you:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash    

shopt -s nullglob

dir=video
for file in "$dir"/*.*; do
    out=$dir/video-${file##*.}

    [[ -d $out ]] || mkdir -- "$out" || continue
    mv -- "$file" "$out"
done
```

You can also specify extensions with: `in "$dir"/*.{avi,mkv,h264}`.

Comment: Make sure you understand how the *parameter expansion* works (they are incredibly handy for string parsing) See `man bash` under *Parameter Expansion*.

Comment: Tweak -- to protect against whitespace `out="$dir/video-${file##*.}"` (you cover it everywhere else)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Not needed in variable assignment. However, I will add an explanation for OP on the parameter expansion later, good idea :)

Comment: Ooh, quite right - `man bash` under `PARAMETERS` paragraph following `name=[value]`. (I would still quote it, because I doubt 99% know the finer points of when it applies -- there is a lot to be said for the better-safe-than-sorry route `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin True, it's a force of habit though :) Just like not quoting `$out` inside `[[...]]`.